# Where did I go wrong with this sampling of a unbiased dice Q? (2 Parts)

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, central-limit-theorem

Q) An unbiased dice is thrown once. Write down the probability distribution of the score $X$ and show that $Var(X) = 35/12$

(Completed: $ \mu = 7/2, \sigma^2 = 35/12$ )

The same dice is thrown 70 times:

I: Find the probability that the mean score is less than 3.3

$P(X \le 3.3) $

$Z = X-\mu/\sigma$

$\implies Z = 7/2 - 3.3/\sqrt(35/12)$

$\implies Z=0.117$

$\implies Ans = \phi(0.117)$

$\implies = 0.5464$

(Correct Answer = 0.155)

II) Find the probability that the total score exceeds 260.

$ 260/70 = 3.714$

$\implies P(\bar {X}\ge 3.714285)$

$\implies 1-\phi(X-\mu/\sigma)$

$\implies 1-\phi(0.414285/1.707825128)$

$\implies 1-\phi(0.242580457)$

$\implies 1-0.5960$

$\implies = 0.404$

(Correct Answer: 0.139)

Comment: DOn't you want $Z=(X-\mu)/\sigma$?

Comment: I used that in both Part A and Part B; in Part B I took the mean to be 3.3 and X to be 3.714285, i.e. leaving the numerator as 0.414285, and i took the denominator; S.D. to be Root of Var(X) = 1.707825128

Comment: This is all wrong though

Comment: I think you may have forgotten that the standard deviation of the sample mean is $\sigma / \sqrt{n}$.